# ingress direction in k8s

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx, phpmyadmin

I create ingress with the manifest file below.

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: ingress-phpadmin
   annotations:

     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /


 spec:
 ingressClassName: nginx
 rules:
   - http:
       paths:
       - path: /
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
             name: apache-php
             port:
               number: 80
   - http:
        paths:
     - path: /phpadmin
       pathType: Prefix
       backend:
         service:
           name: phpadmin
           port:
             number: 80'
```

I went to path /phpadmin
[the result /phpadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Libs.png)

when I logged in phpmyadmin, it return root path and can't go to phpadmin
[after logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0saRJ.png)

How can I prevent path in phpmyadmin  back to root path? thank you.

Comment: remove the annotation and try without that `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`

Comment: Hi! after I removed "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /" and I went to www.website.com/phpadmin page is not found, the error "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server." returned.

Comment: can you try with seperating out both ingress first keep diff name and apply in another with phpadmin add rewrite annotation

Comment: @HarshManvar , I try to apply with 2 diff name ingress files and add rewrite annotation in phpadmin. It can access phpadmin without log in page. Currently, I'm concern in security for my website. Is it anyway that move to "phpadmin" page and the page asks to fill username and password?